# Are HTTP requests nested, in terms of timing?

Tags: http, tcp

**Context:** I am making a web server

**Example:** Let's say there is a file *index.htm* that contains some markup which includes an image.

First, the client sends a request to the server for *index.htm*. The server then responds with the markup.

**Question 1**

Does the server send all the markup to the client before the client sends a second request for the image?

OR

Does the client send the request for the image before all markup is received from the server?

**Question 2**

If all markup is received before further requests, is the connection closed and a new one opened for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the server send all the markup to the client before the client sends a second request for the image?

Yes. The client will only initiate requests for resources mentioned in the HTML after the initial HTML document has been fully received and successfully parsed.

This is why for performance means it is necessary to deliver the complete DOM as fast as possible.

> If all markup is received before further requests, is the connection closed and a new one opened for the image?

That depends. HTTP supports persistent connections, but browsers can also try to open multiple simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 0):

The client (the browser) needs to get the HTML document in order to decide what files will be loaded next. There are many reasons for this type of design. I can think of a few, but others may know more about this.

1. Some HTTP requests (most non-human requests) are not interested in the picture files.
2. It would be very labor intensive and inefficient for the web server (that may receive millions of requests per hour) to parse its outgoing HTML file (for every single incoming HTTP request!!) and decipher what pictures might need to be sent. The parsing of the HTML is the job of the browser who MUST parse the HTML in great detail anyway for other reasons that have nothing to do with data transfer (formatting, layout, elegantly dealing with coding errors in the HTML).
3. Often the embedded pictures (from different domains) exist on other web servers. Clearly the browser must do the work to get these pictures. Why not get all pictures?
4. Much data transfer over HTTP is JavaScript-related. It would be a further nightmare for the web server to have to analyse all the JavaScript of the outgoing page. Handling JavaScript is (typically and/or largely) the job of the browser.

A note: Some web servers do process JavaScript for preprocessing of files. And there are some web server architectures that are based on JavaScript (most significantly, node.js). But this is diverging from your question.

Your second question is more complicated. Later versions of HTTP allow for reusing the same connection for multiple GET or POST transactions. I am not an expert here. Please read here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Hope that helps.

Comment: I may have misuderstood your first question. Since the browser may have several connections open simultaneously it is hard to predict which order the data will arrive in. This is based on the implementation details of how the browser manages data transfer. This probably varies from browser to browser. I am not sure about the answer.